# Android - Scaling image being captured of device screen

Tags: android, image-processing, screenshot

Done with taking a screenshot of (my own screen) device and saving it as an image on sdcard. But I have been observed that images which are captured on devices of different screen size are also varies accordingly.

For example, a screenshot taken on 320 X 480 size device gives same image resolution (width X height).

Is there any possible way to scale image which is being captured to set a fixed image resolution (probably 800 X 600) without losing the quality even captured on small device.

Suggest any sample/algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am using Canvas to scale an image which is been snapshot. No compromising the quality/clarity of image.

```
Canvas bitmapCanvas = new Canvas();
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth()*2, view.getHeight()*2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bitmapCanvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
bitmapCanvas.scale(2.0f, 2.0f);
view.draw(bitmapCanvas);
```

Make sure you give only power of 2, other wise improper scaling results.

Originally answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13602615/1443981).