# How to screen shot a ImageView without lost quality

Tags: android, screenshot

I have two `ImageView`'s in a `RelativeLayout`, the first one is as large as the `RelativeLayout` size (as background),and the second `ImageView` has a small image, now I want to combine these to `ImageView`'s image into one by screenshot. not by combine two bitmap directly.

In the snippet below, I successfully take screenshot of the `RelativeLayout`, ***but I found the image quality is not as good as the first `ImageView`'s bitmap***, can anyone help me please?

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
view.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
Bitmap drawCache = view.getDrawingCache(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get bitmap using window DecorView :

```
View window = activity.getWindow().getDecorView()

Canvas bitmapCanvas = new Canvas();
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(window.getWidth()*2, window.getHeight()*2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

bitmapCanvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
bitmapCanvas.scale(2.0f, 2.0f);
window.draw(bitmapCanvas);

bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, myOutputStream);
```

Ref : [High resolution screen shot in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468020/high-resolution-screen-shot-in-android)

Comment: thanks for answer,but what i want is to get a screenshot of View ,not whole window